# Adding integers to an ArrayList depending on the modulus of their indexes

Tags: java, arraylist, modulus

```
import java.util.*;
public class AddingIntegers{

     public static void main(String []args){
        ArrayList <Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(10,20,30));

        add(list);
     }


public static void add(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            list.add(list.get(i));
        } else {
            list.add(0, list.get(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list);
}

}
```

Expected output: [20, 10, 20, 30, 30, 10]

Actual output:  [20, 10, 20, 30, 30, 20]

So I don't understand why, for the last index, when i = 0, 20 is added at the end of the list, which should be 10 as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: It's a terrible idea to iterate over an array and add to it simultaneously. I was going to ask why you've got 6 elements in the output while the size of `Arrays.asList(10,20,30)` is 3.

Comment: Because, as @rgettman described it below very well, on each iteration you are change original list and you can't relay for positions of original elements, you need to create new list to build desired order.

Comment: what was your `mystery1()`, by the way? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's see what happens with each loop.  Start: `[10, 20, 30]`.

- i = 2

  The expression `i % 2` is `0`, so the element at index 2 (`30`) is appended to the end of the list.  The list is now `[10, 20, 30, 30]`.
- i = 1

  The expression `i % 2` is `1`, so the element at index 1 (`20`) is inserted at the beginning of the list.  The list is now `[20, 10, 20, 30, 30]`.  Note that `20` is now at the beginning of the list.
- i = 0

  The expression `i % 2` is `0`, so the element at index 0 (`20`) is appended to the end of the list.  The list is now `[20, 10, 20, 30, 30, 20]`.  Note that `20` is appended, not `10`, because `10` is no longer at the beginning of the list, `20` is.